# How to monitor multiple music instruments via headphones?

Tags: practice, equipment, headphones

I'm relatively new to the technological side of music. My guitar amp has a speaker cable output, as does my keyboard. I would like to be able to plug both of those, and also a microphone into a device which I can plug headphones into and listen while I play and sing. I'm trying to keep quiet because of apartment neighbors.

What kind of device would allow me to do this? I did some googling and searching here and I saw a lot of recommendations for JamHub, but it seems that company has gone under. A lot of those recommendations were for devices with multiple outputs whereas I only need one headphone output for myself to listen to. Any help would be appreciated, I have no idea where to start.

I looked on Amazon, is something like this ([Alto Professional ZMX52](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B004TM31QK)) what I'm looking for?

Answer (score 1):

As you say, you don't really need something like the jamhub, which provides multiple headphone outs. You're correct that all you really need is a small analogue *mixer* - like the one you linked to, but there are many, many models available.

If your guitar amp really only has a *speaker* out, you won't want to plug that directly into the mixer, as it will be too powerful to be plugged into the 'line level' inputs on the mixer. If your amp has a line out or even a headphone out, that would be more appropriate to plug into the mixer.

If you're not wanting to get distortion or other effects on your guitar, and you just want to be able to hear it, a mixer with a high impedance or "hi-Z" input would let you plug the guitar straight in. (Hi-Z channels are often the same ones as the mic channels - the particular mixer you linked to only seems to have one mic channel, so it might not be the best choice for plugging your guitar straight in to).

One more suggestion - it might sound a little 'claustrophobic' to listen for long periods to your 'dry' voice and guitar through headphones. A mixer with some built in effects (for example, the Yamaha MG06X - manual [here](https://uk.yamaha.com/files/download/other_assets/0/330990/mg06x_en_om_c0.pdf)) might make it more fun to use for extended periods.

Comment: Thanks for the response! Yeah I completely overlooked the fact that there's a headphone out on the amp, sorry about that! I will use that for the mixer. For the headphone out, would I use a 3.5mm to trs splitter like this? https://www.amazon.com/UGREEN-Splitter-Computer-Multimedia-Speakers/dp/B00ZKM3S4S/

Comment: @Jax if your headphone socket is 3.5mm, yes, it does look like the right thing - you'd then be able to plug it in to (for example) 2/3 or 4/5 on the Alto mixer. (just to be accurate that's a 3.5mm *trs **to*** 6.35mm **ts**).

Answer (score 1):

I have the Mackie version of that mixer but it has 3.5mm input so you can wire in your phone , computer or whatnot. It also has USB, which is handy. They should be less than $200. It has high x channels 1 and 2. Nice little unit and it’s always nice to have a mixer, especially a small one.